# How to get late binding in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

The following is a trivial React App component implemented in Javascript...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      setting: "def",
      limit: 2
    }
  }
  updateState(element,  data)
  {
    this.setState({ [element]: data});
  }
  componentDidMount()
  {
    this.updateState("setting", "ghi");
    this.updateState("limit", 4);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <p>
          setting = {this.state.setting}, limit = {this.state.limit}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Note that the updateState method uses late binding to set a member of the state.

The same approach cannot be used in Typescript.  Here is the same component in typescript...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

interface IProps {
}

interface IState {
  setting: string;
  limit: number;
}
class App extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      setting: "def",
      limit: 2
    }
  }
  updateState(element: string, data: any)
  {
//    this.setState({ [element]: data});  // generates error
  }
  componentDidMount()
  {
    this.updateState("setting", "ghi");
    this.updateState("limit", 4);
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <p>
          setting = {this.state.setting}, limit = {this.state.limit}
        </p>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Note that the contents of updateState are commented out because of typescript compiler errors.  How to fix this without using a switch statement?

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: @zam error: Argument of type '{ [x: string]: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IState...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error probably occurs because properties are omitted.

Make properties in `IState` optional.

```ts
interface IState {
  setting?: string;
  limit?: number;
}
```

Comment: This isn't correct. updateState already allows you to pass in as many or as few fields as you'd like

Comment: You're confusing typescript into allowing the object that's a string map by removing all its properties. This has made typescript less sad but now you're left with a updateState method with no type checking, which defeats the point of even typing the state

Answer (score 2):

This will limit element to keys of IState and ensure that the data value matches the type of that field:

```
updateState<E extends keyof IState>(element: E, data: IState[E])
{
    this.setState<E>({ [element]: data});
}
```

keyof IState is a list of all the keys in IState. In this case it's `'setting' | 'limit'`

The generic E ensures that element is a key of IState. IState[E] ensures that data of the same type as the type of IState[element]

Comment: Yes, I like it.  However still need optional properties in IState for this to work.

Comment: Agreed. Trying to figure that one out at the moment. The type hinting to the function works perfectly but you're right it doesn't match setState's requirements yet. The optional fields seems like a dirty hack .... but ... it doesn't break setState's type checking

Comment: @AQuirky I got there in the end. Turns out the setState generic wasn't getting the right type from { [element]: data} because it has no fields. If you let setState know that an allowed field is E then it works fine. I think when all fields are optional it's deciding that setState doesn't require any fields